# Multiple downloading of files wihtout locking the UI in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, download

I am having an array that contains different urls, and a set of buttons, each link is assigned to each buttons. When clicking on a button, the content in the url which is assigned to that particular button will be downloaded. The user can click on multiple buttons at the same time so that multiple download can perform at the same time. And at the same time user should have the provision to navigate through another views, so that the downloading process should not lock the UI. Which would be the best and easiest way to implement this? Please share your ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fetch the data asynchronously:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           // The code here is executed when the response from the request comes back.
                           // The variable "data" will contain the response from the data.
                           // So you can do something like:
                           UIImage *anImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]];
                       }];
```

Comment: thanks for  the reply, is there any sample tutorial which explains the complete process how to use this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean—if you just paste in the above snippet, data will be fetched from the URL asynchronously, so that the main thread isn't blocked. Once the data is downloaded, whatever code you replace the comment with will be executed on the main thread, with `response`, `data`, and `error` bound based on the response from the request. What more would you need to know?

Comment: i thought, it would need some delegate methods thats why I asked.

Comment: I would have mentioned it in my answer if you needed to do anything else :)

Comment: thats cool, thanks. i have given a link to a image in place of url and i started downloading, how can I get the data using this? I new to this, please help

Comment: thank you so much, is there any way to show the loading progress on UIProgressView? using this method?

Comment: I literally have no idea. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Luke, use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) lib with asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily implement a **Asynchronous [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

i.e. each time the user hits that button you fire up an async connection to do the dirty work.

There are plenty of examples - One of the easiest blog style examples to understand is Matt Gallagher's Cocoa With Love. [Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html) is a link.

The gist of the technique is the delegate methods are easy to work with and you can capture each file that you download inside them.

Don't be tempted by the Synchronous style connection as it is not as flexible and you will struggle to make an easy solution for downloading multiple files using that technique.